# How to control the target frame of reporting services (SSRS) drill down

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am using SQL 2005 reporting services (SSRS) with the web report viewer control. It is showing the report inside an IFRAME on the web page. If I implement a drill down functionality, by attaching a URL action to a chart elements, the navigation will happen only inside the IFRAME. I know how to set the target frame for navigation on a normal HTML page. But in the report definition (RDL) I can't find any property to select the target frame.
Any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmm it appparently didnt post my last reply. You might try adding the rc:LinkTarget querystring parameter to the IFRAME src. I use "&rc:LinkTarget=_blank" on some charts displayed in an IFRAME and they open the full report correctly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188712.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the RDL has that option built in.  Try adding it as a connect item and see if they will add it to a future version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the HTML Render method, and pass some DeviceInfo parameters, you can accomplish this.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395.aspx

There is a LinkTarget property that would handle this.